# How to specify different resources in a child/parent relationship in an Azure ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-aks

Trying to put together an Azure ARM template right now.

However, it seems I can create links between resources in very different ways.

Here for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/2019-04-01/virtualnetworks

I can now specify `subnets` for the `virtual network` either under `.resources` or `.properties.subnets`.

Another way is to create another resource `Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets` on its own and then add a `.dependsOn` key to reference the `virtual network` resource id.

Which is the way to go by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mortiz When you use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/2019-04-01/virtualnetworks, you are creating **a new virtual network and associating subnets under that virtual network**.

On the other hand when you use `Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets`, **you are just creating subnets under already existing virtual network** which is usually added as a `.dependsOn`

Comment: Thanks. These two differences make sense. However, what about `.resources` and `.properties.subnets`?

Comment: You create a subnet under `.resouces` using `Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets`. To associate a virtual network with created subnets, you would have to use `.properties.subnets` under `Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks`